# Using Javascript's string.link and onclick together

Tags: javascript, pagination

Is it possible to use the javascript string.link and onclick function together. What I am trying to do is create pagination links for navigating through the website.I have two functions: `pagination` and `showpagination` as given below.

```
function pagination(currentpage){
  if(currentpage<5) {
    start = 1;
    end = 10;
    function showpagination(start,end,currentpage); 
  } else {
    start = currentpage -4;
    end = currentpage + 5;
    showpagination(start,end,currentpage);
  }
}

showpagination(start,end,current) {
  here i loop through the array from start to end.
}
```

What I want to do is to display each pagenumber as a link and then on being clicked trigger the pagination function with its value. I tried tying the string.link and the onclick together but it doesnt work.

If anyone knows of workaround this problem please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the use of keyword `function` before the first `showpagination` intentional?

Comment: I have written the code to explain the functionality.It has not been written in accordance with the syntactic rules.

Comment: @user1219539 if you haven't written the code to work yet, how do you know if you have problems?  have you tried anything yet?

Comment: the problem is not the code but how do i get the link and the onclick function to work together.